# file downloader downloading 0 BYTE file in PHP

Tags: php

My code don't work all times . Most of the time it download 0 BYTE image . I can download particular images by this code and may be this code save the size of the image in the cash by it's name . If i rename the image , it download 0 BYTE .

```
$file_path= $full_path;

$file = pathinfo($file_path);

$base = $file['basename'];

$dir = $file['dirname'];

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$base);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($base));
ob_clean();
flush();

$path = $dir."/".$base;

readfile($path);

exit;
```

Comment: Have you checked if url_fopen is turned on for your server?

Comment: No , I didn't check it . The server is my PC , and it's in a real IP . How can I check it ?

Answer (score 0):

This code fix my problem ....

```
function download($path)
{
// if file is not readable or not exists
if (!is_readable($path))
    die('File does not exist or it is not readable!');

// get file's pathinfo
$pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
// set file name
$file_name = $pathinfo['basename'];

    $mime = 'application/octet-stream';

// set headers
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: -1');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: $mime");

// read file as chunk to reduce memory usages
if ( $fp = fopen($path, 'rb') ) {
    ob_end_clean();

    while( !feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0) ) {
        print(fread($fp, 8192));
        flush();
    }

    @fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

`}`

```
download($file_path);
```